# Export Android Contacts to XML File?

Tags: android, xml, contacts

As a little school project, I'm trying to create a very simple export application for Android.
At first, all I want exported is the contact list - and then import it into another device.
I have two devices for testing - One running 2.2.3 and another running 4.0.4.

I've been playing around with the following pieces of code to accomplish getting the contacts information, and then saving an XML file to the external storage:

```
package com.example.contacts;

import java.util.ArrayList;




import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String num = "nope";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GetContacts();


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}




public String GetContacts() {


ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
        null, null, null, null);
if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
          String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
          String con = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
          if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
                cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
             Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                       null,
                       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                       new String[]{id}, null);
             while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                 String num =             pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                 Log.d("Contacts: ", "Name: " + con + ", Number: " + num);
                 return num;
             }
            pCur.close();
        }
    }
}
return num;

}


}
```

This code successfully prints my contacts to the log.

The next code simply creates an XML file at the device's external storage (SD card) - Taken from http://www.anddev.org/write_a_simple_xml_file_in_the_sd_card_using_xmlserializer-t8350.html:

```
package com.example.contacts;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Xml;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class XmlFileCreator extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //create a new file called "new.xml" in the SD card
    File newxmlfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/new.xml");
    try{
            newxmlfile.createNewFile();
    }catch(IOException e){
            Log.e("IOException", "exception in createNewFile() method");
    }
    //we have to bind the new file with a FileOutputStream
    FileOutputStream fileos = null;        
    try{
            fileos = new FileOutputStream(newxmlfile);
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            Log.e("FileNotFoundException", "can't create FileOutputStream");
    }
    //we create a XmlSerializer in order to write xml data
    XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
    try {
            //we set the FileOutputStream as output for the serializer, using UTF-8 encoding
                    serializer.setOutput(fileos, "UTF-8");
                    //Write <?xml declaration with encoding (if encoding not null) and standalone     flag (if standalone not null)
                    serializer.startDocument(null, Boolean.valueOf(true));
                    //set indentation option
                    serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-    output", true);
                    //start a tag called "root"
                    serializer.startTag(null, "root");
                    //i indent code just to have a view similar to xml-tree
                            serializer.startTag(null, "child1");
                            serializer.endTag(null, "child1");

                            serializer.startTag(null, "child2");
                            //set an attribute called "attribute" with a "value" for <child2>
                            serializer.attribute(null, "attribute", "value");
                            serializer.endTag(null, "child2");

                            serializer.startTag(null, "child3");
                            //write some text inside <child3>
                            serializer.text("some text inside child3");
                            serializer.endTag(null, "child3");

                    serializer.endTag(null, "root");
                    serializer.endDocument();
                    //write xml data into the FileOutputStream
                    serializer.flush();
                    //finally we close the file stream
                    fileos.close();

            TextView tv = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.result);
                    tv.setText("file has been created on SD card");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Exception","error occurred while creating xml file");
            }
    }
}
```

Now, my question is as follows:
How would one proceed to add the strings of contacts to the XML file?
I guess I would have to add tags like this:

starttag: Contacts
starttag: Name :endtag
starttag: Number :endtag
 : endtag

But how can I write these contact details to the child tags of the first "contacts" tag?
Any reference would be lovely.

Answer (score 0):

I would make my life easier and not write the XML 'string' myself but use a serializer like [simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/), have a look at the examples and reference, it's really easy to use.